# Path Issue PHP, Apache, .htaccess or Other?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path

I took over a web application and am currently trying to get it set up for my local dev envrionment. I migrated the DB and everything seems to be working except for some paths which are defined in the .htaccess file presented below. In particular, when I click on links corresponding to "projects", "career" and others, I get "Can't connect to the server." What is more, if I inspect the site in Safari's Web Developer tools, I also see that many CSS and JPG files are marked red, i.e., their paths cannot be found.

Now, I have virtual hosts set up on my local development environment. Initially, I thought that it maybe the problem, but when I try the direct path to some asset in the browser, it finds and opens it.

What could be the issue here? The live site runs 5.5.14 PHP and I have 5.5.27. Does it make sense to try downgrading? Or is the problem somewhere else entirely?

```
Options +Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
   php_value post_max_size 50M
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://blog.xxxxxx.com
  Header append Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Requested-With
</IfModule>



RewriteRule    ^$ _wrapper.php?page=index [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^signup$ _wrapper.php?page=signup [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^verify/(.*)/(.*)$ _wrapper.php?page=verify&email=$1&email_verification_code_hash=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^lost_password$ _wrapper.php?page=lost_password [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^password_reset/(.*)$ _wrapper.php?page=password_reset&password_reset_code=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^password_reset_action$ _wrapper.php?page=password_reset_action [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^create$ _wrapper.php?page=album_create [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^login$ _wrapper.php?page=login [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^gift-cards$ _wrapper.php?page=gift_cards/digital [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^gift-cards/purchased/([0-9a-f-]+)$ _wrapper.php?page=gift_cards/purchased&guid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^gift-card/details/([0-9a-f-]+)$ _wrapper.php?page=gift_cards/details&guid=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^faq$ _wrapper.php?page=faq [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^approach$ _wrapper.php?page=approach [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^projects$ _wrapper.php?page=projects [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^career$ _wrapper.php?page=career [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^career/([0-9]+)$ career/success [QSA,R]
RewriteRule    ^career/success$ _wrapper.php?page=career_success [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^blog$ _wrapper.php?page=blog [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^historian$ _wrapper.php?page=historian [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^terms$ _wrapper.php?page=terms [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^privacy$ _wrapper.php?page=privacy [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^help$ _wrapper.php?page=help [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^fb_albums$ _wrapper.php?page=fb_albums [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^fb_album/(.*)$ _wrapper.php?page=fb_album&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^profile$ _wrapper.php?page=profile [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^profile/edit$ _wrapper.php?page=profile_edit [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)$ _wrapper.php?page=album&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/photos$ _wrapper.php?page=album_photos&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/review$ _wrapper.php?page=album_review_photos&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/people$ _wrapper.php?page=album_people&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/create_account$ _wrapper.php?page=album_create_account&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/details$ _wrapper.php?page=album_details&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/view_details$ _wrapper.php?page=album_view_details&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/shipping$ _wrapper.php?page=album_shipping&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/shipping_flash$ _wrapper.php?page=album_shipping_flashdrive&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/checkout$ _wrapper.php?page=album_checkout&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/purchased$ _wrapper.php?page=album_purchased&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/survey$ _wrapper.php?page=album_survey&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/proof$ _wrapper.php?page=album_proof&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/proof_title$ _wrapper.php?page=album_proof_title&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album/([0-9]+)/proof/([0-9]+)$ _wrapper.php?page=album_proof_page&album_id=$1&proof_page_id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^album$ / [R]

RewriteRule    ^dropbox$ _wrapper.php?page=dropbox [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^instagram$ _wrapper.php?page=instagram [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^instagram_success$ _wrapper.php?page=instagram_success [QSA,L]

RewriteRule    ^maker/album/([0-9]+)$ _wrapper.php?page=maker/maker_album&album_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^maker/album/([0-9]+)/proof$ _wrapper.php?page=album_proof&album_id=$1&maker=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^maker/proof/([0-9]+)$ _wrapper.php?page=admin/proof&proof_id=$1&maker=1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.xxxxxxx.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxxxxx.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/_wrapper..php?page=profile`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/profile` the base suddenly becomes `/profile/` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: I see. I guess I am still confused as to why it would make a difference when I simply copy the folder from one server to another. Is there a way to change it in one place instead of all the pages?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by finding the code where $BASE_URL is set for the application and adding the case for the xxxxxx.dev server that is run on my local machine.